# How to delete a JSPlumb-Element in a React / Backbone environment?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, reactjs, jsplumb

I have a backbonejs model-collection containing models for JSPlumb nodes (ID, parentIDs). The DOM representation is handled by React (divs with Endpoints). If I delete a model from the collection:

```
nodeCollection.remove(aNodeModel)
```

it gets removed from the DOM with all containing components - nice.

If I now add a new node, the Endpoint is not added. I tracked this issue down to some internals in JSPlumb: If I do a

```
jsPlumb.remove(aNodeModel.id)
```

the Endpoint-problem vanishes but I get a React "Invariant Violation" because the `aNodeModel` was not removed from the nodeCollection.

If I remove the jsPlumb Endpoint manually before I remove the model from the collection:

```
jsPlumb.removeAllEndpoints(aNodeModel.id)
```

the problem remains.

This feels somehow like a deadlock... Any suggestions?

Comment: `nodeCollection.remove` removes it from DOM using react right ? But is it removed from jsPlumb ? I guess React won't be telling jsPlumb to update it's model because it has deleted a node in the DOM.

Comment: yes, this is exactly the problem. I found a solution for this by adding a parameter to the `jsPlumb.remove()` method. With this parameter I can control if the element is actually removed from the DOM. If I set it to `false` I can remove the element from jsPlumb and remove it from my model collection controlled by React after that :-) I posted the changes as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Source roxx.

I solved this problem by adding a parameter to the jsPlumb .remove() method controlling the actual DOM-deletion of the element inside jsPlumb. If I set this to false jsPlumb gets cleaned up nicely an I can let React delete the actual DOM-element after that:

```
jsPlumb.remove(sourceNodeID, false, [false])
```

This are the changes I did to the jsPlumb source in dom.jsPlumb-1.7.5.js, lines 5176 and 5210.

```
var _doRemove = function(info, affectedElements, removeDOMElement) {
  _currentInstance.removeAllEndpoints(info.id, true, affectedElements);
  var _one = function(_info) {
    _currentInstance.getDragManager().elementRemoved(_info.id);
    _currentInstance.anchorManager.clearFor(_info.id);
    _currentInstance.anchorManager.removeFloatingConnection(_info.id);
    delete _currentInstance.floatingConnections[_info.id];
    delete managedElements[_info.id];
    delete offsets[_info.id];

    var actuallyRemoveDOMElement = true;            
    if (removeDOMElement.length > 0) {
      actuallyRemoveDOMElement = removeDOMElement[0];
    }

    if (_info.el) {
      if (actuallyRemoveDOMElement) {
        _currentInstance.removeElement(_info.el);
      }
      _info.el._jsPlumb = null;
    }
  };

  // remove all affected child elements
  for (var ae = 1; ae < affectedElements.length; ae++) {
    _one(affectedElements[ae]);
  }
  // and always remove the requested one from the dom.
  _one(info);
};


/**
 * Remove the given element, including cleaning up all endpoints registered for it.
 * This is exposed in the public API but also used internally by jsPlumb when removing the
 * element associated with a connection drag.
 */
this.remove = function (el, doNotRepaint, removeDOMElement) {
  var info = _info(el), affectedElements = [];
  if (info.text) {
    info.el.parentNode.removeChild(info.el);
  }
  else if (info.id) {
    _currentInstance.batch(function () {
      _doRemove(info, affectedElements, removeDOMElement);
    }, doNotRepaint === false);
  }
  return _currentInstance;
};
```